# Laravel: how to get the url prefix in case of a 404

Tags: laravel, routes

In the `RouteServiceProvider::mapWebRoutes` I add a certain prefix (the "locale" in this specific case):

```
protected function mapWebRoutes(string $prefix = ''):void {
    Route::prefix($prefix)
        ->middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

Later on in some blade template I want to get this prefix:

```
    $currentRoute = Route::current();
    $prefix = ($currentRoute) ? $currentRoute->getPrefix() : '';
```

This all works well until I go to some non-existing page and get a 404 (like `https://www.somedomain.com/nl/some-non-existing-page`). The prefix is already correctly determined (since `mapWebRoutes` is already executed), but `Route::current()` is now empty so I can't call `getPrefix()` on it. Is there any way to still get the prefix from Laravel? Something in the line of `Route::prefix()` would be the best.

Of course I can store the prefix in some global var my self, just in case we hit a 404 but I rather get the prefix back from Laravel, since it should know the value at that point.

Comment: You might want to look at `request()->segments()` which will return all segments of your `url`.

Comment: @Unflux That's indeed what I do before calling the `mapWebRoutes` but I just don't want to "calculate" it again in case of a 404